# Visual Studio Code hangs with reconnecting to kernel when using PIL.Image

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

VS Code Version: 1.76.1 (Universal)

Pillow: 9.4.0 (py310h07496d3_2    conda-forge)

```
import PIL
from pathlib import Path

img_name = Path.home()/'tmp'/'testing.jpg'

PIL.Image.open(img_name)
```

I ran the above code in a Jupyter notebook in Visual Studio Code, and it immediately provoked "Reconnecting to the kernel ..."

[image]

just wonder if anyone seen this. Note that if I tried the above with just the good old Jupyter notebook, it is displaying the jpeg correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The investigation and workaround is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13073

If you think you have the same cause, use your judgment 'cos the solution may affect your global python and packages.